# Why the checkout spinner keeps spinning in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, performance, magento2.1.5

It has always worked and now suddenly the spinner in the checkout keeps spinning and doesn't stop loading... I flushed cache again but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your M2 version?

Comment: Magento 2.1.5  -

Comment: generally this kind of thing happens because you have a javascript conflict or because you haven't compiled in production mode. Check for javascript errors or missing files.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands below in order to compile the static files, flush the cache, reindex, upgrade modules installed in the database, and set permission to the essential folders.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf vendor/* var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
composer install && composer update -vv;
php -r "opcache_reset();"
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:static-content:deploy && 
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: Sadly that did not work :c

Comment: try to run composer update -vv on your root install folder

Comment: I don't think this constitutes an answer to this specific question. It just states miscellaneous commands that might be helpful

Comment: Hi @ScottAnderson, I thought the commands were selfexplanatories, but I just added a description about them at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which payment gateway your using its hard to narrow down, but I did see a number of people on magento2 github tracking a similar issue based on Authorize.net from July of 2016.

One solution is to check that your posting from HTTPS and not HTTP to ensure it doesn't fail for security reasons.  Some others on the issue noted that you might have a proxy or CDN that is blocking the callback URLs.

> gamort writes: Your payment processor setup is invalid. Moreover as with the 2.0 bug you had checking out from an http form while submitting via authorize.net directpost is not supported.
>
> In this case at least the error message is quite clear: your server is blocking authorize.net from confirming the order.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5642

Comment: Well.. For me the Spinner does spin forever before I even get to type in my personal information. Its not at the payment step. its as soon as I reach the checkout and need to type in my mail address. it keeps spinning.

Comment: any javascript errors that might indicate whats going on in your console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: element.prop is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (page-cache.js:40)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
    at lookup (page-cache.js:27)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (page-cache.js:30)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
    at lookup (page-cache.js:27)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (page-cache.js:30)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)

Comment: When under NET view do you see it hanging on any specific URL?  Might help point to what file its hanging on.  Also, have you made any theme updates recently before this started happening?

Comment: I already had this problem once. Then after re-enabling a specific plugin "stripe payment method" it worked again. Now there is the problem again and im not even sure if it is because of that plugin... The Spinner already keeps loading whenever you enter the first checkout step. I tested it on 2nd checkout step and there it hangs aswell..

Comment: Found it what it is. I integrated "zendesk chat" to my magento2 store by adding the following Code into the "Footer" Miscellaneous HTML box:

Comment: <!--Start of Zendesk Chat Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
$.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?4plIuP6YixMnTehM0OILkpIzOEVGQ72w";z.t=+new Date;$.
type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
<!--End of Zendesk Chat Script-->